# Timer runs in different thread than the one that created it

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

Using Visual Studio 2015, visual C# windows application.

I need a timer that empties a queue in the main thread because some UI components are modified. I coded this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Q = new ConcurrentQueue<amsg>();
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        clsUdpMsg msg;
        while (Q.TryDequeue(out msg)) handleRx(msg);
    }
```

but the Elapsed event executes in a worker thread...?

If I put a timer on the main form at design time the generated prototype is slightly different:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        amsg msg;
        while (Q.TryDequeue(out msg)) handleRx(msg);
    }
```

but this one DOES execute in the main thread context.

The question extends to any thread that creates a timer this way; I thought a timer created in a thread executes the elapsed event in the same thread context.  Am I missing something?

Quick edit: I see where these are different timers, System.Timers.Timer and Windows.Forms.Timer.  So - how do I reliably create timers that will execute in the thread where I create them?

Comment: they are 2 different Timers.  The first is from `System.Timers`, `Windows.Forms.Timer` is the second

Comment: There is 4 timers in .net, there also is `System.Threading.Timer` and `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you're just dealing with two separate `Timer` classes.  `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` fires its `Tick` event on the main thread and `System.Timers.Timer` fires its `Elapsed` event on a background thread.  The advantage of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is that it hides the threading; the advantage of `System.Timers.Timer` is that it doesn't require a message pump to work.

You ask, "How do I reliably create timers that will execute in the thread where I create them?"  Well, this is easy when you have a Windows Forms GUI and are starting the Timer on the UI thread: just use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  If you don't have a message pump to take advantage of, you have to use a `System.Timers.Timer` and basically the only way to run something on the main thread when the timer fires its `Elapsed` event is to recreate something like a message loop in your main thread--have it sit, maybe waiting for a `Monitor.Pulse` or some other kind of notification from the timer thread.  But this means your main thread won't be getting anything useful done in the meantime...

Comment: So it looks like the best practice is to assume all timer events are not threadsafe... in this case I can use the windows timer.  Thanks for lightning-quick answers!

Comment: I don't quite follow you here.  What do you mean by "all timer events are not threadsafe"?

Comment: The event is threadsafe, the question is whether or not your handler is. If you don't have to worry about the UI thread then if at all possible the best thing would be to have a threadsafe handler so you don't care what thread it runs on.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion to avoid issues with threading of timers.

You could always use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-WinForms").

Your code would look like this:

```
var subject = new Subject<clsUdpMsg>();

var subscription =
    subject
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(msg => handleRx(msg));
```

The `subject` replaces your`Q`. Whenever you want to add a message you just call `subject.OnNext(msg)`.

The `.ObserveOn(this)` marshalls the call back to the UI even if the call to `subject.OnNext(msg)` is made on a background thread.

If you want to stop the subscription just call `subscription.Dispose()`.